# Api requests are returning nothing

Tags: foursquare

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=52.349998,4.917&client_id=myKey&client_secret=myKey&v=20160101&limit=50&categoryId=4d4b7104d754a06370d81259

returns

```
{"meta":{"code":200,"requestId":"57584284498eb387bce1a614"},"response":{"venues":[],"confident":false}}
```

It just starting doing this today before it worked perfectly.

Comment: This issue started yesterday for me. You are not the only one affected.

Comment: It seems like this is happening when a top-level categoryId is provided. Will post an update when this is resolved

Comment: This is happening again today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I emailed the foursquare API team regarding this issue at the following address: api@foursquare.com

I received the following email from them

> Thanks for reporting this - I really apologize for the errors! We are
>   looking into into the issue and working to get it resolved. It appears
>   to only be effecting venue/search requests that supply a top level
>   categoryId and ll. Please let me know if there's any other info
>   regarding this error.

So once the issue is addressed, the API requests should start working again.